# How to match a number to two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

The main goal of this is to cycle through the array and see if you have the winning number but I can't figure out how to do it? Then I have to match that winning number to the bet I made with it which I also can't figure out how to do.

```
public class FinalRoulette {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number[];
        number = new int[37];
        int bet[];
        bet = new int[37];            
        int numbers = 1;
        double x = 38, totalwager = 0, money = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
            while (numbers > 0) {
                System.out.print("What number do you want to bet on-"
                    + "enter 0 to stop betting: ");
                numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
                number[i] = numbers;
                System.out.printf("How much do you want to bet?: ");
                bet[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
                totalwager += bet[i];        
            }

        int randomnum = 0;
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        randomnum = randomNumbers.nextInt(37);
        System.out.println("The winning number was " + randomnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. First advise is to be exact with the variable names. It is so easy to confuse number and numbers, especially when numbers is only a single number, but number is an array of numbers.  Maybe call numbers betNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Get a number then check if the number in the array:

```
int bet = keyboard.nextInt();

for (int number : numbers)
    if (number == bet)
        // bet found in array
```